# Ajax based page compatibility with events

Tags: jquery, ajax, events

I am designing a page kind of Google news or Google reader (i.e. a page full of data and events). I planned totally to make this page ajax-based. There is also a feature of topics as it in [Google News](https://news.google.co.in/) (shown in the left-sidebar). I also planned to add a feature to add topics to this current list of topics. But unlike google I am providing a input field on top of this sidebar. User can directly add a topic by typing anything in it. **The problem** is when I added this new topic there is no event attached to it that are attached to all other topics.
What I mean when I am adding new html to page it does have any event attached to it.
After searching over SO I found that to bind events i can use `.live()`.   But `.live()` is deprecated from Jquery on behalf of `.on()`. But `.on()` don't provide future event attachment I think. (there is nothing written about future event handling in its documentation)

Now I have only added a topic. But I have to add many new html on the go. Is there an method to attach event to them. Presently I attached events on the basis of `.class`.

What is the best way to add HTML using ajax which already have events attached to it.

Any further suggestions about this topic because I think right now I am a noob in this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **.on** in the same way you use **.live**, you can bind the **.on** event to **document** itself for future elements, like

```
$(document).on("click",".yourDynamicElement", function(){  
  console.log('i have been clicked'); 
});
```

Or you can replace **document** with your already existing parent/container element of the dynamically created element

Did you mean something like that

Comment: If i replace document with any selector then .on is not working for future elements. Why this is happening? What is the logic behind using document?